# Ruby: How to create a block and pass it as an argument?

Tags: ruby

I'm working with a method that takes a block as an argument. I'm new to Ruby and Blocks, so I don't quite understand how I would go about creating a Block and passing it to the method. Can you please provide me an example of how you would create a block and pass it as an argument?

**Update:** Here is an example of the method that I am trying to call:

```
def exec!(commands, options=nil, &block)
  # method code here
  # eventually it will execute the block if one was passed
end
```

Here is how I am currently calling this method:

```
@result = ssh.exec!("cd /some/dir; ls")
```

How do I pass a block as the third argument to the `exec!` method?

Comment: Based on your example, you'd just use `do/end` or `{}` to create the block. If it yields something to the block, you'd use vertical bars `|foo|` to access whatever it yields in your block, like the `each` example in my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends partially on how you want to use it. An *easy* way is this, if it fits your usage needs:

```
@result = ssh.exec!("cd /some/dir; ls") do |something|
    # Whatever you need to do
    # The "something" variable only makes sense if exec! yields something
end
```

Or

```
@result = ssh.exec!("cd /some/dir; ls") { |something| puts something }
```

The `{}` notation is generally used when the block is short.

You can also create a `Proc` or lambda; ultimately the "right" answer depends on what you're trying to do.

Note there's [an example](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Connection/Session.html#M000093) if you're talking about Net::SSH.

Comment: So in your example, is foo the method that I am calling? And the block gets created automatically when do/end comes next?

Comment: @Andrew `foo` is the method that's being called, correct. (I slightly misread your question, I thought you were also creating the method.) But yes. Things like `each` are methods that take a block, so `aList.each { |item| puts item }` is doing the same thing--the block is passed to the `each` method.

Comment: Thanks! You really cleared it up for me. Also, thanks for the link to the example. I'm actually using a library that wraps Net::SSH so I didn't know about that example.

Comment: oh, what happens when there is a second argument (like the optional options argument in my example)? Does it get ignored some how, or would I need to pass `nil` as the second argument?

Comment: @Andrew Since it has a default value specified, I don't *think* you'd need to pass nil--why not just try it?

Answer (score 3):

And one more thing. You can also create Proc-object (or any object that have 'to_proc' method) and call your method with that Proc-object as last argument with '&' symbol before it. For example:

```
proc = Proc.new { |x| puts x }
%w{1 2 3}.each(&proc)
```

other way to doing the same thing:

```
%w{1 2 3}.each { |x| puts x }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using keyword **yield** for understanding the passing block argument?

For example we have:

```
def our_method
  puts "we're going to call yield operator"
  yield "this is message from our_method"
  puts "we called the yield operator"
end

our_method { |message| puts message }
```

We will get this result:

```
we're going to call yield operator
this is message from our_method
we called the yield operator
```

How it works?

When we called the **our_method** we also passed to it the argument, in our case it's a block -

`{ |message| puts message }`.

In the **our_method** it executes first string and will print **"we're going to call yield operator"**.

And then it's the turn of **yield** operator. It almost equivalent to `block.call` but besides this it's passing the **message** to the block as an argument. 
That's why the block will print string from our_method.

In the end the our_method prints final string **"we called the yield operator"**.